# Reading a participant list from a .csv into C# program

Tags: c#, csv

I'm writing a small program that reads some people's firstname, surname, ID and email from an Excel sheet into the console, which isn't the problem, but instead of getting this output:

```
Poul EjnarRovsingpersomething@mail.com
ReneBach2014914something@mail.com
JohnJohnsson3950185something@mail.com
```

I want the output to be similar to this:

```
Poul Ejnar   Rovsing   per        something@mail.com
Rene         Bach      2014914    something@mail.com
John         Johnsson  3950185    something@mail.com
```

The code I'm using is giving me this output, which is certainly a step in the right direction, but not quite what I'm looking for:

```
Poul Ejnar   Rovsing   per   something@mail.com
Rene   Bach   2014914    something@mail.com
John   Johnsson   3950185   something@mail.com
```

And for some reason it's only outputting every other row instead of all of them, which is also puzzling me quite a bit. What am I missing here?

This is my code:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] tokens;
        char[] separators = {';'};
        string str = "";
        string newSeparator = "   ";


        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Dokumenter\Skole\6. semester\GUI\Exercises\Exercise2\02 deltagerliste.csv", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default);



        while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            str = sr.ReadLine();
            tokens = str.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Console.WriteLine(tokens[0] + newSeparator + tokens[1] + newSeparator + tokens[2] + newSeparator + tokens[3]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You'd have to determine the longest value in each column to determine what amount of spacing to add to line up the next column.

Comment: Tools for reading csv exist. Your case is simple, but still a case of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Magus Yep, tools like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Answer (score 1):

#### Fixed Width Outputs

For fixed width formatting, you can take advantage of [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and alignments using `String.Format`. For example:

```
String.Format("{0,10}", "name"); // output blocks of 10 characters, right aligned
String.Format("{0,-10}", "name"); // output blocks of 10 characters, left aligned
```

Format strings are of the form: `{index[,alignment][:formatString]}`. To left align an item, use a negative value for alignment.

To use this in a composite format string, you just add more format placeholders in curly brackets, the index corresponds to the index of the argument in `String.Format`:

```
var sString = "name";
var anInt = 1;
var aDecimal = 1.23M;
var s = String.Format("|{0,10}|{1,10:0}|{2,10:0.00}|", sString, anInt, aDecimal);
```

Output:

```
|      name|         1|      1.23|
```

#### Line skipping

And, it is skipping every other line as every time you iterate in the `while` loop, you read one line, then read again:

```
while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null) // <--- first read
    {
        str = sr.ReadLine(); // <--- second read replaces the first one
```

try a `do` loop with the while and the read at the end

```
str = sr.ReadLine();
do {
    ... do stuff here ...
} while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your constructive reply!

I tried adding String.Format to my output, but now I only get the first name (the first column out of four in my .csv file). I'm not sure I've understood the usage of String.Format correctly, could you perhaps give an example of it?

Comment: @Left4Cookies. I only gave you the example of a single input, but you can use composite formatting, see the answer update, try that sample in a console app and use `Console.WriteLine(s);` to see the output

Comment: I fiddles around with it some more and got to this piece of code for my output: `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-20}", tokens[0]) + String.Format("{0,-15}", tokens[1]) + String.Format("{0,-15}", tokens[2]) + String.Format("{0,-15}", tokens[3]));` which gave me the desired output from my initial post! Is that the correct usage of the method?

Comment: @Left4Cookies. I would combine it, preferably, to `String.Format("{0,-20}{1,-15}{2,-15}{3,-15}", tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3])`. There are other variations, I'm sure, but that is readable and will work.

Answer (score 0):

You invoke the `ReadLine` twice, and you are skipping a row also use `\t`, this indent your output in tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading every other line because there are two calls to the StreamReader

```
    while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        str = sr.ReadLine(); // Don't need this one!
        ...
```

The first call in the `While` statement will advance the reader one line. The second call will advance it again, overwriting what you previously just read.

To get the spacing correct you could use `\t` to insert tabs, but you would still need to do some math on the size of each token so you can use the correct number of tabs. Alternatively you could use [String.PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make each column a specific length.